# Checking whether the inputs are numbers

Tags: python, if-statement

I have this code and I wonder how to make this with using if and whether.

```
num1 = input("Choose first number: ")
num2 = input("Choose second number: ")
try:
    val = int(num1)
except ValueError:
    print("The first input is not a number!")
try:
  val = int(num2)
except ValueError: print ("The second input is not a number!")
```

I know that it makes the same but on the level that I am it is better for me to use. If You could I would love it if you could describe how it works. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my approach would be to exclude the input functionality with a function an then assign to variables

This way, you can still ask for the users input even after they wrongly kept a non-int

```
def inputer():
    val = 0
    try:
        val = int(input('Choose your number: '))
        return val
    except ValueError:
        print("The input is not a number!")
        return inputer()
    

num1 = inputer()
num2 = inputer()
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it now is a good way. `input` from python always takes a string as input. The best way is to just try to make the string into a integer or float.

If you want to take all the digits out of a string you can play around with regular expression [w3 tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp).